# Comparing User input to list 'A' and converting the characters of input to list 'B' based on the index of list 'A'

Tags: python, string, list

Designing a program for a school project the encrypt/decrypt user input based on the index of 2 lists. The issue im having is indexing the lists, and comparing the user input to the index so the output to the screen = list2

all of the code is very basic using 'str' and 'input' in the variable name as to not confuse myself.

```
list1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','.','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

list2 = ['4','R','5','G','Z','3','2','D','A','E','X','Y','U','I','6','W','7','O','V','8','F','Q','0','L','J','.','H','9','C','B','N','S','P','M','1','T','K']
```

```
strInput = input("Type the message you would like to Encrypt  ").upper()
inputList = split(strInput)
print(inputList)
i = 0

for char in inputList:
    if inputList[i] != list1[i]:
    i = i + 1
```

Now from here it should take the user input, compare locations on each list via the index, and then print the text to the screen using the other list. I just cant figure out my indexing problem.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers work though you may want to consider a `dict` for faster speed. A python dictionary is a table of key value pairs (hash table to be technical). The table uses the key to find the value. When you search for something in a `dict` is has a constant look up time O(1), meaning the `dict` does not search through itself for the element. It knows exactly where it is (if it has it).

**For Example:**

```
d = {
   2: 'A',
   5: 3
}
print(d[2]) # This will print the letter A
print(d[5]) # This will print the number 3
```

Your lists:

```
list1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','.','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

list2 = ['4','R','5','G','Z','3','2','D','A','E','X','Y','U','I','6','W','7','O','V','8','F','Q','0','L','J','.','H','9','C','B','N','S','P','M','1','T','K']
```

Turned into a `dict`:

```
# The following will zip your two lists together into a dictionary
# list1 will be the keys, and list2 will be the values.
encription_dict = {list1[i]: list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))}
```

Then we can encrypt:

```
# Get the user input
strInput = input("Type the message you would like to Encrypt  ").upper()

# The following is list comprehension 
new_str = [(key_val[char] if char != ' ' else ' ') for char in strInput]

# That one line was equivalent to:
# new_str = []
# for char in strInput:
#     if char != ' ': # if it is not a space
#         new_str.append(key_val[char]) # Add the encrypted char for this char
#     else:
#         new_str.append(' ')

# Turn the list into a single str.
new_str = ''.join(new_str)

print(new_str)
```

**Testing:**
Input:   `Test 2`
Output:  `8ZV8 C`

Comment: Great idea. I would explain why this is faster. Seems like he is just getting started.

Comment: @brandonbanks good point. I added comments and explained the `dict` in more detail.

Comment: That was really helpful! I have not touched on dictionaries yet so it had not crossed my mind.

Comment: @GreenBeanie91 Feel free to ask questions if you need help with it :).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the character in the first list by using `.index(char)`

```
list1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','.','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

list2 = ['4','R','5','G','Z','3','2','D','A','E','X','Y','U','I','6','W','7','O','V','8','F','Q','0','L','J','.','H','9','C','B','N','S','P','M','1','T','K']

str_input = 'TEST'

encrypted_chars = []

for char in str_input:
    if char == ' ':
        encrypted_chars.append(char)
    else:
        encrypted_chars.append(list2[list1.index(char)])

encrypted_message = ''.join(encrypted_chars)  # 8ZV8
```

You can also use python's list comprehension [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
encrypted_chars = [(list2[list1.index(char)] if char != ' ' else ' ') for char in str_input]
encrypted_message = ''.join(encrypted_chars)
```

To decrypt you would basically do the opposite of this.

```
decrypted_chars = [(list1[list2.index(char)] if char != ' ' else ' ') for char in encrypted_message]
decrypted_message = ''.join(decrypted_chars)
```

Answer (score 0):

A. I'm not sure where you were going with your code or exactly what the assignment is, but I think I did it for you.

B. Don't get in the habit of having others do your homework for you, you won't learn

```
list1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','.','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']​
list2 = ['4','R','5','G','Z','3','2','D','A','E','X','Y','U','I','6','W','7','O','V','8','F','Q','0','L','J','.','H','9','C','B','N','S','P','M','1','T','K']

inputList = input("Type the message you would like to Encrypt  ").upper().split()
print(inputList)

encrypted_message=[]
for word in inputList:
   for char in word:
       encrypted_message.append(list2[list1.index(char)])

print(encrypted_message)
```

So for example the string 'you will fail the exam' gives `['J', '6', 'F', '0', 'A', 'Y', 'Y', '3', '4', 'A', 'Y', '8', 'D', 'Z', 'Z', 'L', '4', 'U']`

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I was looking more for insight not answers but anything is helpful and your input is greatly appreciated!